# Why is my variable invisible to the debugger in an action method?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have the weirdest problem. For a quick test of instantiating my role provider, I run the following modified action method:

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    Educ8RoleProvider p = new Educ8RoleProvider();
    var model = new LoginModel();
    return View(model);
}
```

The role provider looks more or less like this:

```
public class Educ8RoleProvider : RoleProvider, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IMemberRoleRepository _memberRoleRepository = new MemberRoleRepository();

    public Educ8RoleProvider()
    {
    }
}
```

The code in `Login` executes without any exceptions, but when I put a break point on the line `var model = new LoginModel();`, variable `p` has vanished. I get the same error trying to place a quickwatch on `p` as I do trying to inspect it in the immediate window:

```
The name 'p' does not exist in the current context
```

This morning I upgraded from VS11 Beta top VS2012 RC. I don't know if this might be due to a new setting somewhere or something.

**ADDED:** I found I had somehow strayed off my Debug config onto a release based one.

Comment: This sounds to me like the debug symbols are not loading properly. I don't recommend it as a first course of action, but you may need to uninstall/reinstall completely. Here is an article to check where your symbols are loading from or to specify a location: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x54fht41.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that it's been optimized away - after all, you're not *using* it for anything.

I'd expect it to be okay on a debug build, but gone for an optimized build. (The constructor should still be called, of course.)

I question whether you should have it at all if you're not going to use it, mind you - it's *at least* a code smell.

If this is really for a "quick test of instantiating [your] role provider" might I recommend unit tests instead? :)

Comment: Thanks Jon, I am indeed coming back to write some proper unit tests for this, but I really just needed a very quick and dirty check, until I found this problem. See my edits please.

Answer (score 0):

Weird.  Only thing that springs to mind is that maybe VS2012 knocks variables out of scope the last time they are referenced.  Have you tried putting in a line to access p after and see if it lets you watch it then?